# How to run a VBA code that copies a range of cells from an active sheet and paste it in a new workbook (only values and formatting and no formulates)?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to run a macro where I click on the start button and the active sheet gets updated by fetching the data from a row. This data then gets stored into a new workbook (only values and formatting). I want this operation to continue till the ith row so that I will have i separate workbooks at the end of the execution. For this I have made two name ranges: rng_counter that stores the start row number and rng_forms_count that stores the end row number and in my loop I increment this rng_counter till it becomes equal to rng_forms_count. However the problem I am facing is that after running through the fist iteration successfully, the code throws an error "Method range of object_global failed". One thing I also noticed that each time I fire the start button, the excel automatically sets the formula calculation as manual and the rng_counter doesn't get updated. I am using the following code:

```
For i = Range("rng_counter").Value To Range("rng_forms_count").Value

    Range("rng_counter").Value = i
    Calculate
        If Worksheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("C9").RowHeight > 165.6 Then '***This part is to mention an issue that would come up in the report made
            MsgBox "There is an issue with the AEs of Respondent ID - " & Range("rng_ae_number") & ", the AE form would extend beyond the intended height of the form,(write down this Respondant ID and do it seperately, its report would not be generated) consider reducing the font size of AEDump to make sure the report comes in 2 pages instead of 3!"
        Else 
                Sheets("Reporting Form Template").Select
    Range("A1:Q14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

     End If
        Next i
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: are `Range("rng_counter")` and ` Range("rng_forms_count")` in the same sheet "Reporting Form Template"?

Comment: no they are in a different sheet where I have the "start button". The row data pulls up in this sheet one by one and from this sheet it gets copied into the sheet "Report form template" using simple = formulas

Comment: how/where is the code that copies data from the "button" sheet to "Report form template" sheet?

Comment: your issue is you switch between worksheets and workbooks without using fully qualified ranges: see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue lays in

1)  the lack of fully qualified ranges up to their worksheet and workbook parents

2) the `Workbooks.Add` that will make the newly created workbook the "Active" one and its first worksheet the "Active" one, too

So, since after your comment I got you're running a sub triggered by an ActiveX button and that both  `Range("rng_counter")` and `Range("rng_forms_count")` are in that very same sheet while all other ranges are not, you may want to try this (explanation in comments):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Me ' reference the sheet with button

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        Dim i As Long
        For i = .Range("rng_counter").Value To .Range("rng_forms_count").Value

            If Worksheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("C9").RowHeight > 165.6 Then '***This part is to mention an issue that would come up in the report made
                MsgBox "There is an issue with the AEs of Respondent ID - " & .Range("rng_ae_number") & ", the AE form would extend beyond the intended height of the form,(write down this Respondant ID and do it seperately, its report would not be generated) consider reducing the font size of AEDump to make sure the report comes in 2 pages instead of 3!"
            Else

                .Range("rng_counter").Value = i 'update "rng_counter" named range in referenced sheet
                Calculate

                .Parent.Worksheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("A1:Q14").Copy ' copy a fully qualified range up to its workbook parent

                With Workbooks.Add ' open and reference a new workbook. this will become tha "active" one
                    With .Worksheets(1).Range("A1") ' reference referenced workbook first worksheet (which has become the "active" one) range A1
                        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    End With
                End With

            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the issue was the point 2 that you mentioned. It is working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wBook As Workbook
For i = Range("rng_counter").Value To Range("rng_forms_count").Value

    Calculate
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("C9").RowHeight > 165.6 Then '***This part is to mention an issue that would come up in the report made
        MsgBox "There is an issue with the AEs of Respondent ID - " & i & ", the AE form would extend beyond the intended height of the form,(write down this Respondant ID and do it seperately, its report would not be generated) consider reducing the font size of AEDump to make sure the report comes in 2 pages instead of 3!"
    Else 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("A1:Q14").Copy
        Set wBook = Workbooks.Add()
        With wBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Q14")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats      
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
    End If
Next i
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error now on "Worksheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("A1:Q14").Copy". It says subscript out of range. Can you please help?

Comment: Hi thanks! Sorry the error still remains. Is there an alternative I can try?

Comment: I change the order in the code... try now. If 1st iteration successful - pls write

Comment: yes 1st iteration was successful. On second iteration, the code stopped at  If Worksheets("Reporting Form Template").Range("C9").RowHeight > 165.6.

Comment: You open new workbook, it become active and no such sheets in this workbook. you can close new workbook after paste or activate you workbook after creating wbook or specify Sheets every time when you use it. I prefer last choice.